# how to iterate through result set and return N rows per group in result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So far I have a cte query that returns a result that i would like to iterate over the result set and select 2 records per group based on type column ie... 
I could return 2 rows for type 20, return 2 rows for type 21, return 2 rows of record for type 22 ect...  I've tried a few functions on here but there always returning 2 records instead of 2 records per above mentioned .  Thanks

```
Acct    Cde  type AcctNbr
123456  50  20  2345678 
123457  50  20  2345678 
123458  50  20  2345678 
123459  50  20  2345678
123460  50  21  2345678
123461  50  21  2345678
123462  50  21  2345678
123463  50  21  2345678
123464  50  22  2345678
123465  50  22  2345678
123466  50  22  2345678
123467  50  22  2345678
123468  50  23  2345678
```

I'm trying to return at least 2 rows per type column . I've used a cte with 
main query and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how you'd choose *which* two rows you want, so I've arbitrarily chosen to order by Acct. Then use the [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to number the rows by type.

```
WTIH YourFirstCTE AS (
    -- Appropriate code goes here
),
cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT Acct, Cde, type, AcctNbr,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY Acct) AS RowNum
        FROM YourFirstCTE
)
SELECT Acct, Cde, type, AcctNbr
    FROM cteRowNum
    WHERE RowNum <= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, I just tried this out and it worked like i wanted it to.  I had to edit the code to remove the second "WITH"  since this was multiple CTE.  Again thanks